# vuetifyjs: Adding only used icons to build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, material-design-icons

I'm currently build a vuetifyjs-app with the default "Material Design Icons". In the production build I only use 2 Icons of this font (used by vuetify-component chips).

As recommend I included the complete iconfont with

`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

But the production-build this force the user to download almost 0.5MB of Data only for 2 icons.
Is there any way to:

- Include only needed Icons in the CDN-Request
  or
- Use Tree-Shaking to include only the icons in need in the main CSS file? (i'm using parcel.js builder)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We recommend using [@mdi/js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mdi/js) where possible. This provides an ES Module which exports the SVG path of every icon in the icon set and supports treeshaking. You simply pass the icon string to an SVG path element or in this case you can pass it directly to `v-icon` if you specify the icon font in the Vuetify config: `iconfont: 'mdiSvg'`.

**Installation**

```
npm install @mdi/js
```

**Usage**

```html
<template>
  <v-icon>{{ mdiCheck }}</v-icon>
</template>

<script>
  import { mdiCheck } from '@mdi/js'

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      mdiCheck,
    }),
  }
</script>
```

You can read more about integration with Vuetify here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons#install-material-design-icons-js-svg

Comment: Thank you! With hindsight this is clear from the docs but this issue has been driving me nuts for the past week!