# Add only needed icons to the build

Tags: vuetify.js, material-design-icons

I have the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57552261/vuetifyjs-adding-only-used-icons-to-build), i.e. my build is currently including half a megabyte of unused icons. The solution given in that answer doesn't work for me (the icons don't show), perhaps because I am using a newer version of Vuetify. I have followed the installation of `@mdi/js` and use of icons given in that answer, which also says

> You simply pass the icon string to an SVG path element or in this case you can pass it directly to v-icon if you specify the icon font in the Vuetify config: iconfont: 'mdiSvg'.

If I try that in my config, I get an error:

> 'iconfont' does not exist in type

```
const vuetify = createVuetify({
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdiSvg',
        defaultSet: "mdi",
        aliases,
        sets: {
          mdi,
          fa,
        },
      },
      components: {
        VDatePicker,
      },
    directives,
  })
```

I am using the icons as below. If I include the full MDI set, as I have been doing, `mdi-bike` shows up, but `mdiMap` does not

```
  import { mdiMap } from '@mdi/js'
  ....
  ....
  <v-tab :value=Tabs.routes><v-icon :icon="mdiMap"></v-icon>All routes</v-tab>
  <v-tab :value=Tabs.newRide><v-icon>mdi-bike</v-icon>New Ride</v-tab>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no `iconfont` property in Vuetify 3 icon configuration.

The [documentation for Vuetify 3](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#mdi-js-svg) shows how to register the SVG iconfont:

```js
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi-svg' // <---- use SVG icons

export default createVuetify({
  icons: {
    defaultSet: 'mdi',
    aliases,
    sets: {
      mdi,
    },
  },
})
```

As explained in the other answer, this means that you have to import all icons not used by Vuetify:

```html
<script setup>
import { mdiAlertCircle } from '@mdi/js'
</script>
<template>
  <v-alert :icon="mdiAlertCircle" />
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you (yet again!) Moritz. I had missed adding `-svg` to the import. Build package now 1.5 Mb smaller.